# predict label for new text input on trained model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, prediction

I'm trying to do a prediction on new text examples, where I want the prediction to return a probability output for each example.

This is my learning model:

```
with tf.name_scope('Placeholders'):


input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sequence_length], name='input_x')
  input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes], name='input_y')
  drops = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='dropout_keep_prob')

with tf.name_scope('Embedding_layer'):
  embeddings_v = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
  embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params=embeddings_v, ids=input_x)

# Bi_directional LSTM
with tf.name_scope('Bi_directional_LSTM'):
  rnn_outputs, _ = bi_rnn(LSTMCell(hidden_unit), LSTMCell(hidden_unit),inputs=embeddings, dtype=tf.float32)
  tf.summary.histogram('Bi_directional_LSTM', rnn_outputs)

# Attention layer
with tf.name_scope('Attention_layer'):
  attention_output, alphas = attention(rnn_outputs, attention_size, return_alphas=True) 
  tf.summary.histogram('alphas', alphas)

with tf.name_scope('Dropout'):
  drop = tf.nn.dropout(attention_output, drops)

with tf.name_scope('Fully_connected_layer'):
  W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_unit * 2, n_classes],stddev=0.1))
  b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0., shape=[n_classes]))
  y_hat = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(drop, W,b)
  predictions = tf.argmax(input=y_hat, axis=1, name='predictions')

with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_hat, labels=input_y))
  global_step = tf.Variable(0.1, name="global_step", trainable=False)
  optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
  probs = tf.nn.sigmoid(y_hat)
  tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
  correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_hat,1), tf.argmax(input_y,1))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32), name='accuracy')
  num_correct = tf.reduce_sum(input_tensor=tf.cast(correct_pred, 'float'), name='correct_predictions')
  tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)
 
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

I then run the following piece of code to train the model:

```
def batch_generator(X, y, batch_size):
    """batch generator"""
    size = X.shape[0]
    X_copy = X.copy()
    y_copy = y.copy()
    indices = np.arange(size)
    np.random.shuffle(indices)
    X_copy = X_copy[indices]
    y_copy = y_copy[indices]
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i + batch_size <= size:
            yield X_copy[i:i + batch_size], y_copy[i:i + batch_size]
            i += batch_size
        else:
            i = 0
            indices = np.arange(size)
            np.random.shuffle(indices)
            X_copy = X_copy[indices]
            y_copy = y_copy[indices]
            continue
            
train_batch_generator = batch_generator(x_train, y_train, batch_size)
test_batch_generator = batch_generator(x_dev, y_dev, batch_size)
predict_generator = batch_generator(x_test, y_test, batch_size)

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True))) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print("Start learning...")
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        loss_train = 0
        loss_val = 0
        loss_test = 0
        accuracy_train = 0
        accuracy_val = 0
        accuracy_test = 0
        train_loss_l = []
        val_loss_l = []

        print("epoch: {}\t".format(epoch), end="")

        # Training
        num_batches = x_train.shape[0] // batch_size
        for b in tqdm(range(num_batches)):
            x_batch, y_batch = next(train_batch_generator)
            loss_tr, acc, _, summary = sess.run([loss, accuracy, optimizer,merged],
                                                feed_dict={input_x: x_batch,
                                                           input_y: y_batch,
                                                           drops: 0.5})
            train_loss_l.append(loss_tr)
            accuracy_train += acc
            loss_train = loss_tr * DELTA + loss_train * (1 - DELTA)
        accuracy_train /= num_batches
            
        # Validation
        num_batches = x_dev.shape[0] // batch_size
        for b in tqdm(range(num_batches)):
            x_batch, y_batch = next(test_batch_generator)
            val_loss, val_acc, summary = sess.run([loss, accuracy,merged],
                                                     feed_dict={input_x: x_batch,
                                                                input_y: y_batch,
                                                                drops: 0.5})
            val_loss_l.append(val_loss)
            accuracy_val += val_acc
            loss_val += val_loss
        accuracy_val /= num_batches
        loss_val /= num_batches

        print("loss: {:.3f}, val_loss: {:.3f}, acc: {:.3f}, val_acc: {:.3f}".format(loss_train, loss_val, accuracy_train, accuracy_val))

    # predict x_test
    num_batches = x_test.shape[0] // batch_size
    print("n batches",num_batches)
    predict_correct = 0
    for batch in tqdm(range(num_batches)):
        x_batch, yx_batch = next(predict_generator)
        y_true = np.argmax(yx_batch,1)
        loss_pred, acc_pred, n_correct, y_pred = sess.run([loss,accuracy,num_correct,predictions], feed_dict={input_x: x_batch,input_y: y_batch,drops : 0.5 })
  
    
    print("Precision", sk.metrics.precision_score(y_true, y_pred,average='weighted'))
    print("Recall", sk.metrics.recall_score(y_true, y_pred,average='weighted'))
    print("f1_score", sk.metrics.f1_score(y_true, y_pred,average='weighted'))
    print("confusion_matrix")
    print(sk.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred))
    
    saver.save(sess, MODEL_PATH)

    sess.run(predictions, feed_dict={x: x_test})
```

The code runs fine until it hits the prediction part where I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Any chance someone could explain this to me please?

Comment: can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: sorry I just solved my own problem... will add solution now :D

Comment: it's even better well done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answered my own question...

This is just in case someone else is attempting to do this. If you feed tensors to feed_dict, just use the actual placeholder name you used before.

In my case this would be:

```
print(sess.run(predictions, feed_dict={input_x: x_test,drops:0.5}))
```